# Handling multiple experimental annotations throughout an app

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-experimental

I have an app that makes heavy use of experimental features for Jetpack Compose so I have to declare a bunch of annotations on the composables. Since these annotations require callers to also declare them I have ended up in a situation where I have an activity with the following code:

```kotlin
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

import androidx.compose.material.ExperimentalMaterialApi
import androidx.compose.ui.ExperimentalComposeUiApi

import com.google.accompanist.navigation.material.ExperimentalMaterialNavigationApi
import com.google.accompanist.pager.ExperimentalPagerApi
import com.google.accompanist.permissions.ExperimentalPermissionsApi
…

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    @ExperimentalPermissionsApi
    @ExperimentalComposeUiApi
    @ExperimentalPagerApi
    @ExperimentalMaterialNavigationApi
    @ExperimentalMaterialApi
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        // … wiring up compose code (which propagates the experimental annotations)
```

An alternative to avoid this situation would be to use the `@OptIn` instead but since only one is allowed per declaration it doesn't work out for my case with multiple experimental features.

Any way… This works fine — In Kotlin 1.5.

With Kotlin 1.6 I am getting a compilation error:

> Opt-in requirement marker annotation on override requires the same marker on base declaration

But the base declaration is in the standard API that I cannot change.
**How can I make this compile (and work as before)?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I got tired of my code being polluted by all those annotations. The easiest way to get rid of them and have your code compile is just add this to your top build.gradle file - It's not exhaustive. Just add more compiler arguments for each annotation you need:

```
allprojects {
    tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).all {
        kotlinOptions {
            freeCompilerArgs += [
                    "-Xuse-experimental=kotlin.ExperimentalUnsignedTypes",
                    "-Xuse-experimental=kotlinx.coroutines.ExperimentalCoroutinesApi",
                    "-Xuse-experimental=kotlinx.coroutines.InternalCoroutinesApi",
                    "-Xuse-experimental=androidx.compose.animation.ExperimentalAnimationApi",
                    "-Xuse-experimental=androidx.compose.ExperimentalComposeApi",
                    "-Xuse-experimental=androidx.compose.material.ExperimentalMaterialApi",
                    "-Xuse-experimental=androidx.compose.runtime.ExperimentalComposeApi",
                    "-Xuse-experimental=androidx.compose.ui.ExperimentalComposeUiApi",
                    "-Xuse-experimental=coil.annotation.ExperimentalCoilApi",
                    "-Xuse-experimental=kotlinx.serialization.ExperimentalSerializationApi",
                    "-Xuse-experimental=com.google.accompanist.pager.ExperimentalPagerApi"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works well, though "use-experimental" is now deprecated. I've added my own response with a referral to this answer which deals with deprecation and is in Kotlin DSL instead of Groovy DSL

Comment: @Alix what's the replacement?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70220590

Answer (score 30):

### TLDR;

`@ExperimentalAnimationApi` ❌
This annotation means - "This is an experimental API, all users have to explicitly opt in to use". Rarely the case for application developers.

`@OptIn(ExperimetalAnimationApi::class)` ✅
This annotation means - "I am opting in to use an experimental api". It does not force the users of this method/class to add annotation in their code.

[Opt-In Requirements | Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/opt-in-requirements.html)

### Problem

```
@ExperimentalAnimationApi
@Composable
fun MyCode()
```

means `MyCode` is experimental animation api, if you want to use `MyCode`, explicitly opt in to `ExperimentalAnimationApi`

```
@Composable
fun MyOtherCode() {
  MyCode() // ERROR!, doesn't compile and shows red underlines in IDE
}
```

is what typically causes too many `@ExperimentalAnimationApi` annotations in our code. **DO NOT DO THIS**

### Solution (fix compilation, IDE warnings)

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalAnimationApi::class)
@Composable
fun MyCode() {
  // experimental animation api usage
}
```

will **NOT** force the callers to add any annotations

```
@Composable
fun MyOtherCode() {
  MyCode() // safe, compiles and doesn't show any errors in IDE
}
```

As app developers, we almost always have to 
use `@OptIn(ExperimentalAnimationApi::class)` and 
**NOT** `@ExperimentalAnimationApi`, 
unless our code itself is exposing experimental declarations in it's public surface as return types or function arguments etc.

### Solution to only fix compilation

Alternatively we can add

```
tasks.withType<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile> {
  kotlinOptions {
    freeCompilerArgs = freeCompilerArgs + listOf(
      "-opt-in=androidx.compose.animation.ExperimentalAnimationApi",
    )
  }
}
```

but this doesn't remove the IDE underlines etc. So  is not that useful.

Comment: Did they change something in new releases of Android Studio? Currently the fix for compilation removes any warnings and underlines in the source code. I tried with `"-opt-in=androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.SavedStateHandleSaveableApi"`.

Comment: @Xam I guess they fixed the warnings. But I'd still suggest using the annotations as intended instead.

Answer (score 15):

A non-deprecated variation of [@Johanns](https://stackoverflow.com/users/753632/johann) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70217715/1859486) in Kotlin DSL (with some other annotations that I'm using):

Deprecation warning:

> w: '-Xuse-experimental' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release, please use '-opt-in' instead

```kotlin
tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile::class).all {
        kotlinOptions {
            freeCompilerArgs = freeCompilerArgs + listOf(
                // Avoid having to stutter experimental annotations all over the codebase
                "-opt-in=androidx.compose.animation.ExperimentalAnimationApi",
                "-opt-in=androidx.compose.material.ExperimentalMaterialApi",
                "-opt-in=androidx.compose.runtime.ExperimentalComposeApi",
                "-opt-in=androidx.compose.ui.ExperimentalComposeUiApi",
                "-opt-in=com.google.accompanist.navigation.material.ExperimentalMaterialNavigationApi",
                "-opt-in=com.google.accompanist.pager.ExperimentalPagerApi",
                "-opt-in=com.google.accompanist.permissions.ExperimentalPermissionsApi",
                "-opt-in=kotlin.ExperimentalUnsignedTypes",
                "-opt-in=kotlinx.coroutines.ExperimentalCoroutinesApi",
                "-opt-in=kotlinx.coroutines.InternalCoroutinesApi"
            )
        }
    }
```

Comment: Update - use "opt-in" instead of "Xopt-in".

Answer (score 9):

> An alternative to avoid this situation would be to use the @OptIn instead but since only one is allowed per declaration it doesn't work out for my case with multiple experimental features.

You can put multiple experimental features comma separated into `@OptIn`.

E.g. `@OptIn(ExperimentalComposeUiApi::class, ExperimentalFoundationApi::class, ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This seems to work as well, good to know!

Answer (score 0):

In an multi-module project if you want to centraly define such things, but a given library isn't used in all of the sub-modules you can do it as below - dependent on the libraries you use e.g. when you use Compose set the Compose-Opt-Ins.

In the `build.gradle.kts` (root):

```
subprojects {

     afterEvaluate {
        if (configurations.any { it.incoming.dependencies.any { dep -> dep.group == "androidx.compose" } }) {
            tasks.withType<KotlinCompile>().all {
                kotlinOptions {
                    freeCompilerArgs = freeCompilerArgs + listOf(
                        "-opt-in=androidx.compose.ui.ExperimentalComposeUiApi",
                        "-opt-in=androidx.compose.foundation.ExperimentalFoundationApi",
                    )
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Just a quick note that from Koltin 1.8 and up `compilerOptions` are prefered over `kotlinOptions`