# TextField() - In jetpack compose says "This material API is experimental and is likely to change or to be removed in the future"

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I was coding along with the help of this video,

https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-using-state?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fandroid-basics-compose-unit-2-pathway-3%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fbasic-android-kotlin-compose-using-state#1

I wrote this composable function,

```
@Composable
fun EditNumberField() {
    TextField(value = "", onValueChange = {})
}
```

This TextField() shows red error says

```
This material API is experimental and is likely to change or to be removed in the future
```

I imported this in the beginning of my code,

```
import androidx.compose.material3.TextField
```

Please give me some suggestions on how I can fix this error or suggest some alternatives if it's already been replaced by something else.

Comment: You have to add `Experimental` annotations. If you have multiple usages and you want to handle through out the project, refer to this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70216206/handling-multiple-experimental-annotations-throughout-an-app

Comment: Yes, I can use that, But I want something stable, not experimental.

Comment: Yes, exactly, what is the stable alternative? ... an iPhone text field?

Answer (score 5):

Upgrade dependecy version for Material3 at least to 1.1.0 in build.graddle:

```
implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.0'
```

More info: [here](https://material.io/blog/material-3-compose-1-1)

Comment: thanks! My material3 dependency looked like this: `implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3'`, after adding a version, in my case 1.1.2, the error went away. `implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.2'`

Answer (score 2):

Try to add to your composable item this  `@ExperimentalMaterial3Api`.
If these warnings bother you, add this

```
kotlinOptions {
    allWarningsAsErrors = false
    freeCompilerArgs += [
        '-opt-in=androidx.compose.material3.ExperimentalMaterial3Api'
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be something seriously wrong with Android Studio Flamingo 2022.2.1.
Attempts to create a project all seem to generate TextFields with this problem.

I've managed to work round this way:
To the project file *build.gradle(app)*, in the section *kotlinOptions*, add the line

freeCompilerArgs +=
"-opt-in=androidx.compose.material3.ExperimentalMaterial3Api" (as above).
Then I find I can right click on the error message. From there clicking on *Show quick fixes* allows the app to build,

Comment: OK, but what is the stable alternative? ... there is no way to create an official stable text field with Android using the jetpack compose ?!?

Comment: It does look as if there isn't. I'm sure Android have made some sort of mistake in the current Jetpack release - something as basic as TextField can't always be experimental. I'm waiting for the next release.

Comment: Yes, exactly, let's wait for next releases, Google has the money to do it right ... I hope !!